# A fading effect on a horizontal scrolling table

Tags: css, frontend

Right, so I'm trying to create a fade-effect on just one side of a table that doesn't fit in my resonsive layout, so that the user can recognise that he is able to scroll the table (due to scrollbars being invisible on mobile).

I've used the `box-shadow` on inset with some positioning to create a fancy shadow that falls over the table, but when I scroll it, it's positioned absolutely (obviously, since I specify that) and scrolls along. Instead of staying put.

When I specify the position as `fixed`, the `:after` uses the entire body as its parent, not just its relative parent.

```
.table-holder {
    width: 400px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}

.everything .table-holder:after {
    box-shadow: -20px 1px 20px 0 #f00 inset;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 200%;
    left: -0;
    position: absolute; /* : fixed takes the whole page */
    top: -20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is fiddlable here: http://jsfiddle.net/8enne5qf/1/

Is it at all possible to get this shadow to be fixed on the parent div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the shadow is scrolling because of `table-holder` overflow scroll property wrap `table-holder` in another `div` and give `:after` to it setting it `position:absolute` you can also use gradient instead of box shadow

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/gt7rceLs/1/

```
.everything .shadow:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 25%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    box-shadow: -20px 1px 20px 0 #f00 inset; /** or gradient **/
}
```

Comment: Sweet. I read your reply yesterday, but am not sure if adding an extra div would be feasible, the CMS is huge and I'm trying to figure out if tables are created in just one, or in many different ways. I'll accept your answer, as technically it does definitely answer my question, but not in the way I hoped ;) Thanks!